# Exit Protractor e2e test on fail?

Tags: angularjs, tdd, protractor, angularjs-e2e

Does anyone out there know if there is a config that can be added to protractor's `e2e.conf.js` so it exits the test once it fails? Default behaviour is that if a test fails early on, you need to wait until it finishes to fix the error.

From a workflow perspective, this is very frustrating.

Any solutions to this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

no this option is missing. you could implement [jasmine-bail-fast](https://github.com/goodeggs/jasmine-bail-fast)

Comment: +1 this is the answer. For future reference subscribe to [this feature request](https://github.com/juliemr/minijasminenode/issues/20)

Comment: Thanks @elgalu, this seems to be what i was looking for. Thanks for the tip.