# How to exit a testcase in protractor if element contains value

Tags: angularjs, node.js, testing, protractor, angular-promise

I've been writing a suite of tests in Protractor, and am almost finished.  I'm having difficulty figuring out how to do something fairly common though. I want to be able to check if a textbox contains a value, and if so, exit the testcase with a failure. (If the textbox contains a value, I know there's no chance the test case can pass anyway)

I'm currently trying something like this:

```
    tasksPage.generalInformationDateOfBirthTextbox.getAttribute('value').then(function(attr){
        //attr contains the correct value in the textbox here but how do I return it to parent scope so I can exit the test case?
        console.log("attr length is " + attr.length);
        expect(attr.length).toBe(0);
    },function(err){
        console.log("An error was caught while evaluating Date of Birth text value: " + err);
    });
```

The expect statement fails as I'd expect it to, but the testcase keeps going, which seems to be the intended behavior of expect.  So I tried returning a true/false from within the 'then' block, but I can't seem to figure out how to return that value to the parent scope to make a determination on.  In other words, if I change the above to:

```
    var trueFalse = tasksPage.generalInformationDateOfBirthTextbox.getAttribute('value').then(function(attr){
        if(attr === ""){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    },function(err){
        console.log("An error was caught while evaluating Date of Birth text value: " + err);
    });

    //This is the 'it' block's scope
    if(trueFalse == true){
        return;
    }
```

I know my inexperience with promises is probably to blame for this trouble.  Basically, I just want a way of saying, 'if such and such textbox contains text, stop the test case with a failure'.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

This is not a `protractor` issue, it is a testing framework issue (`jasmine`, `mocha` etc).

Though, there was an issue on `protractor`'s issue tracker:

- [--fail-fast CLI option](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/499)

which was closed with a reference to an *opened issue* in `jasmine` issue tracker:

- [Feature Request - fail-fast option](https://github.com/juliemr/minijasminenode/issues/20)

While this is not implemented, there is a workaround (originally mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25496290/exit-protractor-e2e-test-on-fail)):

- [`jasmine-bail-fast` package](https://github.com/goodeggs/jasmine-bail-fast)

After installing the module with `npm`, when you want your test to fail and exit, add:

```
jasmine.getEnv().bailFast();
```

(don't forget to load the dependency `require('jasmine-bail-fast');`)

---

Also see:

- [Does jasmine-node offer any type of "fail fast" option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562817/does-jasmine-node-offer-any-type-of-fail-fast-option)

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the code above is that you are trying to compare a 'Promise' and a 'value'.

trueFalse.then(function(value)
{
    if(value)
        ....
});

OR compare it via an expect statement. Something like expect(trueFalse).toBe(false);